# How to implement gvrArmModel supplied with Google VR SDK?

Tags: unity-game-engine, daydream

How to implement gvrArmModel supplied with Google VR SDK v1.5 in unity 5.6?

Comment: Do you want to implement your own?  The existing arm model is automatically configured on the prefabs.

Answer (score 0):

Located [here](https://developers.google.com/vr/unity/controller-support) on the developer website is documentation for how to use the controller including GvrArmModel. If this doesn't answer your question I'd be happy to help if you add some additional information about what issue you are facing.